# How to show the statistics of EhCache in the jmx

Tags: spring, caching, jmx, ehcache

I set up some caches to test the caching for some DTOs. Now I want look at the **statistics** from the caches in the **jconsole**. 
The problem is that they **are not provided**.

Maybe, the caches don´t work correctly and this is the reason why there no values in the statistics. But i don't see any error in the code or when i start the server, so i think they must work properly.

My code in the **spring.xml:**

```
<!-- ******************** EhCache DTO caching ************************ -->

<ehcache:annotation-driven create-missing-caches="true" cache-manager="dtoCacheManager" />

<bean id="dtoCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" 
    p:config-location="dtoEhcache.xml" p:shared="true"/>



<!-- ***** register cache with JMX ***** -->

<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
</bean>


<bean id="ehCacheMBeanRegistration" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService.registerMBeans"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="dtoCacheManager"/>
            <ref bean="mbeanServer"/>
            <value>true</value>
            <value>true</value>
            <value>true</value>
            <value>true</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My code in the **dtoEhcache.xml:**

```
<!-- ***** Config for the Caches ***** -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true" updateCheck="false">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/DtoEhCacheSpring" />

<defaultCache eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true" />

<cache name="brandDataCache" eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true" />

<cache name="cmsSiteCache" eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="1000" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true" />

<cache name="contentPageCache" eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="1000" overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="1000"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true" />
```

A example of a Method which should be cached:

```
 @Cacheable(cacheName = "brandDataCache")
public BrandData convert(final BrandModel brandModel, final BrandData prototype) throws ConversionException {
... impl ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the error. It wasn't a problem with the jmx config. It was a problem with the placing of the cacheable annotation. The cache will be only triggert if the method is called from outside the class. I placed it wrongly on a method that is only called inside the class (facepalm). I changed the annotation to the other method and now it works.